# How to select a select type object which has certain text in the id in vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html elements which have keyword 'target' in their ids. I want to select a 'select' elements which contain the key word in their id.

```
<select id="page_blocks_0_buttons_1_target"><option value=""></option></select>
<select id="page_blocks_0_buttons_2_target"><option value=""></option></select>
<select id="page_blocks_0_buttons_3_target"><option value=""></option></select>
<select id="page_blocks_0_buttons_4_target"><option value=""></option></select>
<div id="page_target_div"></div>
```

My current attempt is as follow, but it also returns the div type which i don't want.

```
var targetFields = document.querySelectorAll("*[id*=target]");
```

Comment: This should work .. ```var targetFields = document.querySelectorAll("select[id*=target]");```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) expects a CSS selector-- you are prefixing with `*`, which will select *all* elements-- change it to `select` and it should work as expected.  See the snippet below:

```js
var targetFields = document.querySelectorAll("select[id*=target]");
console.log(targetFields)
```

```html
<select id="page_blocks_0_buttons_1_target"><option value=""></option></select>
<select id="page_blocks_0_buttons_2_target"><option value=""></option></select>
<select id="page_blocks_0_buttons_3_target"><option value=""></option></select>
<select id="page_blocks_0_buttons_4_target"><option value=""></option></select>
<div id="page_target_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:not` to avoid `div`.

```js
var targetFields = document.querySelectorAll("*[id*=target]:not(div)");
console.log(targetFields.length);
```

```html
<select id="page_blocks_0_buttons_1_target">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
<select id="page_blocks_0_buttons_2_target">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
<select id="page_blocks_0_buttons_3_target">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
<select id="page_blocks_0_buttons_4_target">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
<div id="page_target_div"></div>
```